# JQuery - find a radio button by value

Tags: jquery, radio-button

How would I use JQuery to find a radio button by its value?

Answer (score 145, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(":radio[value=foobar]")
```

This will select all radio buttons with the attribute `value="foobar"`.

Comment: Thanks I used it as such:
 jQuery.each(cookieObj, function(i, val) {
  $(":radio[value=val]").attr('checked',true);
 });

Comment: @test: Try this instead: `function(i, val) { $(":radio[value="+val+"]").attr('checked',true); }`

Comment: @Gumbo if we give that function a name, can we call it like so?: $checkedRadioValues = findChecked("value");

Answer (score 27):

I'm using jQuery 1.6 and this did not work for me: `$(":radio[value=foobar]").attr('checked',true);`

Instead, I'm using: `$('[value="foobar"]').attr('checked',true);`
and it works great.

The actual code I'm using clears the radios first and uses `prop` instead of `attr`

```
$('[name=menuRadio]').prop('checked',false);

$('[name=menuRadio][value="Bar Menu"]').prop('checked',true);
```

Comment: is this a bug that was fixed? or should we still put quotes around the value?

Answer (score 19):

This can be achieved by this too:

```
$('input[type="radio"][value="aaa"]').val();
```

This will select the radio which has the value of aaa

---

With `.filter()` method:

```
var radio =  $('input[type="radio"]').filter(function(){
                       return this.value === 'aaa';
                      }).val();
```

Comment: this will actually select all radio buttons and **change their values** to `aaa` then return the `'aaa'`

Answer (score 5):

say you have something like this in the HTML:

```
<fieldset>
    <input type="radio" name="UI_opt" value="alerter" checked> Alerter<br/>
    <input type="radio" name="UI_opt" value="printer"> Printer<br/>
    <input type="radio" name="UI_opt" value="consoler"> Consoler<br/>
</fieldset>
```

then this sort of thing works.

```
$("fieldset input[name='UI_opt'][checked]").val()
```

Answer (score 2):

A full selector would look like this:

```
bool shipToBilling = $("[name=ShipToBillingAddress][value=True]")
```

given that you probably have more than one radio button group like this

```
<input name="ShipToBillingAddress" type="radio" value="True" checked="checked">
<input name="ShipToBillingAddress" type="radio" value="False">

<input name="SomethingElse" type="radio" value="True" checked="checked">
<input name="SomethingElse" type="radio" value="False">
```

Using an ID selector like this (next example) is bad because you shouldn't have multiple elements with the same ID. I assume someone finding this question already knows this is bad.

```
$("#DidYouEnjoyTheMovie:radio[value=yes]")
```

The following about [`:radio`](http://api.jquery.com/radio-selector/) may or may not be of interest

> Because :radio is a jQuery extension and not part of the CSS
>   specification, queries using :radio cannot take advantage of the
>   performance boost provided by the native DOM querySelectorAll()
>   method. For better performance in modern browsers, use [type="radio"]
>   instead.