# jquery find all elements having a certain value

Tags: javascript, jquery

When a user clicks on my radio button:

```
<input type="radio" name="allselect" onClick="javascript: _select('none');" />
```

I need the function _select(param) to find every radio button with a value of param, so 'none' in this case, and click it. How can this be done in jquery?

Comment: What have you tried so far and what in particular do you have problems with? jQuery's documentation is the place to start: http://api.jquery.com/, especially have a look at selectors: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: I looked at the .find function but I didn't see anyway to say 'find all elements WHERE value is this'

Comment: possible duplicate of [JQuery - find a radio button by value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2173527/jquery-find-a-radio-button-by-value)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you **are** using jQuery:

```
<input type="radio" name="allselect" id="selectnone" />
```

JS:

```
$('#selectnone').click(function(){
    $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function(){
          if(this.value === 'none') this.checked = true;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd think that the following, as yet untested approach, would work:

```
$('input:radio').click(
    function(){
        var inputsOfValueEqualToNone = $('input:radio[value="none"]');
    });
```

Making the above into a more function-based approach:

```
function _select(param){
    if (!param){
        return false;
    }
    else {
        inputs = $('input:radio[value="' + param + '"]').click();
    }
}
```

References:

- [`:radio` selector](http://api.jquery.com/radio-selector).
- [attribute-equals (`[attribute="value"]`) selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function _select(param){
   var rBtns = $('input[name=' + param + ']');
   rBtns.click();//Calling the click method on all the radio buttons it found
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
function _select(paramVal){
   $('input[value=' +paramVal +']').trigger('click');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
function _select( value ) {
  var elems $('input:radio[value='+value+']'); // all the radio buttons with the value
}
```