# Get inner html of the selected option by value NOT INDEX in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have HTML code

```
<select id="city">
<option value="A">Mumbai</option> 
<option value="B">Bangalore</option> 
<option value="C">Delhi</option> 
<option value="D">Indore</option> 
</select>
```

I want a JavaScript for getting the `innerHTML` of option by its value.

I have tried

```
var selectedValue = document.getElementById('city').value;
var city = document.querySelector('#city option[value='+selectedValue+']').innerHTML;
alert(city);
```

But giving the error

> SyntaxError: An invalid or illegal string was specified

Comment: You might want to check how to do this in jQuery. 
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2173527/jquery-find-a-radio-button-by-value][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2173527/jquery-find-a-radio-button-by-value

Comment: I want a JavaScript code not jQuery

Answer (score 1):

You can use `querySelector` method with `[value=A]` selector :

```
var city = document.querySelector('#city option[value=A]').innerHTML
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/40k362bu/)

Comment: I am trying this code but getting this error querySelector is not defined in console.

Comment: @meetesh : you've missed  `document.` before `querySelector(<...>)`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you might want to do that. Neways, here it is :

```
<select id="city">
<option value="A">Mumbai</option> 
<option value="B">Bangalore</option> 
<option value="C">Delhi</option> 
<option value="D">Indore</option> 
</select>
<script>
    var city = (document.getElementById('city').innerHTML).split('</option>');
    console.log(GetOptionHtml_ByValue('city', 'B'));

function GetOptionHtml_ByValue(xElementId, xValue) {
    AllHtml = (document.getElementById('city').innerHTML).split('</option>');
Array1 = [];
Array2 = [];
Array3 = [];
Array4  = [];
FoundIndex = -1;
for (i = 0; i < AllHtml.length; i++) {
    str = AllHtml[i];
    Array1 = str.split('<option value="');
    for (j = 0; j < Array1.length; j++) { 
        str2 = Array1[j];
        Array2 = str2.split('">');
            for (k = 0; k < Array2.length; k++) { 
                str3 = Array2[k];
                if ((j==1) && (k==0)) {
                        Array3.push(str3);
                        if (str3 == xValue) FoundIndex = Array3.length -1;
                    }

                if ((j==1) && (k==1))
                    Array4.push(str3);
            }
    }

}

if (FoundIndex > -1) 
    returnme = Array4[FoundIndex];
else
    returnme = 'NOT_FOUND';

return returnme;

}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use the `options` property to get all of the available options, the `selectedIndex` property to know which one is selected, and the `innerHTML` property of the selected option.

```
var cityElem = document.getElementById('city');

var selectedIndex = cityElem.selectedIndex;

if(selectedIndex != -1) {
    var selectedOption = cityElem.options[selectedIndex];
    var optionInnerHtml = selectedOption.innerHTML;
    alert(optionInnerHtml);
}
```

Mind you, if you put HTML inside an option element, it will ignore the HTML tags and just concatenate the text together. This must be done at an early stage of the HTML processing, because by the time you are accessing the values in the javascript, you are just accessing the text. If that's good enough then this solution will work, otherwise you will have to manually parse the inner html of the `select` element.

[The jsfiddle...](http://jsfiddle.net/a2hc1xxz/3/)