# Javascript- find a radio button by value

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button

I am aware that in [JQuery - find a radio button by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2173527/jquery-find-a-radio-button-by-value) is simply

```
$(":radio[value=foobar]")
```

How would I use Javascript to find a radio button by its value?

Comment: Tobias K, you are missing the question here!!!!

Comment: And he down vote 2 answer, just because he misunderstood the entire question!!

Answer (score 1):

If requirement is to not use jQuery, you can use `document.querySelector()` with multiple attribute selector

```
document.querySelector("input[type=radio][value=foobar]")
```

Comment: Question is a duplicate.

Comment: @TobiasK. Question is not a duplicate _" I just want to find the value of the radio button"_ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9618504/get-radio-button-value-with-javascript

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
document.querySelector("input[type='radio'][value='foobar']");
```

Comment: Question is a duplicate.

Comment: @tobiasK. That may be but that doesn't mean my answer is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you meant a non-jQuery way, as jQuery is Javascript :)

A naïve approach would be to filter input elements, determine if it's a radio button and determine the value:

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
var radios = inputs.filter(function(el) {
    return el.type == 'radio';
};
var valueRadios = radios.filter(function(radio) {
    return radio.value == 'foobar';
};
```

Comment: `document.getElementsByTagName()` does not return an array

Comment: Interesting, a HTMLCollection that allows array like access. Doh!